# Django prefetch_related children of children

Tags: django, django-orm

I have a model `Node` that looks something like that:

```
class Node(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='children', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

A Node can have several children, and each of these children can have its own children.

If I do:

```
def show_child(node):
    for child in node.children.all():
        show_child(child)

root_node = Node.objects.prefetch_related('children').get(pk=my_node_id) # hit database twice, as expected
print("Now testing queries")
root_node.children.all()  # no hit
root_node.children.all()  # no hit
root_node.children.all()  # no hit
root_node.children.all()  # no hit
print("Test 2")
show_child(root_node)  # hit database for every loop except the first
```

The database gets hit every time I try to access the children of a child.

How could I make it so that it gets the node, its children, the children of its children, etc, in a single database query?

Comment: Managed to make it work with another approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55205973/django-populate-model-instance-related-field-from-cached-query/55218482#55218482

Answer (score 3):

According to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) you can do this:

```
Restaurant.objects.prefetch_related('pizzas__toppings')
```

This will prefetch all pizzas belonging to restaurants, and all toppings belonging to those pizzas. This will result in a total of 3 database queries - one for the restaurants, one for the pizzas, and one for the toppings.

or you can use the Prefetch object to further control the prefetch operation.

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch

Restaurant.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch('pizzas__toppings', queryset=Toppings.objects.order_by('name')))
```

Comment: I am already using prefetch in my question. What I would like to know is if I can grab everything in a single database query. Also, in my case I can have toppings on toppings on toppings, etc, and I would like to get them all even if I don't know how far the hierarchy goes.

Comment: @RyanPergent You can look into ```select_related```: Returns a QuerySet that will “follow” foreign-key relationships, selecting additional related-object data when it executes its query. This is a performance booster which results in a single more complex query but means later use of foreign-key relationships won’t require database queries. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#select-related

Comment: Yes, thank you but I looked into it already. I can use select_related to prefetch a single item (like a parent) but I cannot use it to get a list of children.

Comment: @RyanPergent Are you sure? there is an example in the docs doing it: then a call to ```Book.objects.select_related('author__hometown').get(id=4)``` will cache the related Person and the related City

Comment: Yes, but `author` and `hometown` are single objects. It wouldn't work with a list like `authors` and `cities` for example.

Comment: @RyanPergent maybe you can look into django-mptt: https://django-mptt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/